# ASP.Net MVC 2 Omitting Properties When Autogenerating View Content For Strongly-Typed View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

This is a simple question but I couldn't find an answer for it online. I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class EquipmentItem : Item
{
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

When I create a strongly-typed view and provide this class, asking ASP.Net MVC to automatically make a view populated with "create" content it leaves out all of the properties in the Status class. Is there a way for me to tell ASP.Net MVC to also provide HTML input fields for the properties in that class?

Thanks

Comment: If you are familiar with T4 templates you could create a custom code template using this heirarchy `CodeTemplates(folder)->AddView(folder)->Create.tt(t4 file)` then probably you would create a custom function to replace this `FilterProperties(mvcHost.ViewDataType, properties);`

Comment: here is an example -> http://goo.gl/71mJm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also do

```
Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Status);
```

Comment: This is probably the best supported method for doing it however my custom class has properties of custom types and it gets too messy with EditorFor. I just ended up making a flat pono and using it. As this answer technically answers the question correctly I'm marking it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I always take it as a sign that you should create a partial view when you have such properties in your view model.

In any case, creating the partial view will allow you to scaffold the properties of your Status class as it would be strongly typed to status, instead of EquipmentItem.

The alternative is to use mapping (eg, AutoMapper), and map your domain model class to your view model class.  The view model class would just have simple properties that MVC will scaffold for you.